# nginx consider swagger UI path to index.html as a route path

Tags: php, nginx, swagger-ui

I have two projects both using identical nginx configurationg, only difference is host name and path to web directory:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name {project_host};

    root /var/www/{project_path}/web;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/{project_name}_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/{project_name}_access.log;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    sendfile off;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

both in the `web` dir has folder `docs` which has all swagger-ui files with `index.html`.

All is working fine for project one, I can get access to swagger ui using url `prject1/docs/index.html`, but in case of project 2 when I going to `project2/docs/index.html` I'm getting my not found page which should be shown by php when a route is not found. Why in case of app 1 nginx understand that `/docs/index.html` is not route but in case of app 2 it's considering it as a route instead of path to the file if configurations the same

My `web` dir structure is (identical for both projects) :

```
web/ 
    index.php
    docs/
         index.html
          other_swagger_ui_files
```

Maybe it'll also be useful, both projects are kind of microservices, and locally I have a docker-compose configuration to start and up them, so they both under the same network and using the same Nginx-proxy container and sharing same PHP container, but each of them has own Nginx container (but as I already told they identical and have identical configuration)

Comment: Have you restarted nginx after saving config?

Comment: sure, btw I did not change Nginx config for a while, but I only today add swagger to the second project. Probably I did not change something, but I can't figure out what. I comparing both projects and configs, all is the same